# random number process in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am absolute beginner for iOS development. But Familiar with JAVA.

My Question is How to access and process the variables of `-(void)viewDidLoad` into `-(IBAction)add`.

Here is my sample code..
in Interface File..
in `ViewDidLoad` I declare `x=10`;
and in `IBAction` I can't able to use that `x`;

Comment: Just like in Java you need to use an instance variable to access the value from multiple methods.

Comment: declare your variable in `.h` file and use it globally in `.m` file !

Comment: @Maulik Why would you declare the variable in the .h file? It should be in the .m file unless other classes need access too.

Answer (score 2):

In your .h file

You've to define your X ivar. (ivar = instance variable)

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController
{
    int X;
}
@end
```

Now you can use that X anywhere from .m file like this,

```
- (void) viewDidLoad {
    x = 10;
}

- (IBAction) add {
    x = x + 10;
    NSLog(@"X = %d", x);
}
```

I am assuming that X is of type integer.

Answer (score 0):

you can easily access the variable

declare x below your

```
 @implementation 
 int x;

 viewDiDLoad {
     x = 10;
 }
```

Comment: This declares a file global variable, not an instance variable. You need curly braces: `@implementation { int x; }`.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make *x* a member variable in .h file.

Like

```
@interface yourClass
{
   int x;
}
```

or you can define your private ivar in your .m file before @implementation

```
@interface yourClass()
{
   int x;
}
```